# React Router sending a state

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I create a list of `Clients`, where the user clicks one of the `Clients` they will Link to the page and send the data as a state. I get the data from `portfolio` that I fetched before using `Context`

```
      {portfolio.map((data) => {
        const { id, name, image, logo, year, title, text, path } = data;
        return (
          <Link to={`/portfolio/${path}`} key={id} state={data}>
            <div
              className={`grid-item grid-item--${id}`}
              style={{
                backgroundImage: `url(${image})`,
                backgroundSize: "cover",
                backgroundPosition: "center center",
              }}
            >
              <img src={logo} alt={name} className="cls-logo" />
              <div className="cls-text">
                <div className="cls-text-wrapper">
                  <h1>{year}</h1>
                  <h3>{title}</h3>
                  <p>{text}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Link>
        );
      })}
```

It succeeds for a moment, then I added a `Link` to make it easier to navigate by adding the `prev` and `next` `Client` if they want to see it.

```
let data = useLocation();
const { id, name, logo, image, text, title, year } = data.state;

  const { portfolio } = useGlobalContext();
  let prev = id - 1;
  if (prev === 0 && portfolio !== []) {
    prev = portfolio.length - 1;
  }

  let next = id + 1;
  if (next > portfolio.length - 1 && portfolio !== []) {
    next = 1;
  }
```

The problems that I'm getting are:

1. Seems that I cant use `portfolio` because it's undefined at the first, so `React` can't catch the values from it.
2. If I comment the `prev` & `next` my code works just fine, and when I hit the refresh button it's also fine. But the problem is when I try to access it directly from the URL since I didn't send any data to the component.

Appreciate any kinda response, thanks before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it appears you have access to the same `portfolio` array in the receiving component as the linking component, I suggest using the dynamic route param as a "search" key to find the matching portfolio element. This avoids the issue of needing the route state to be sent as *that* "state" is easily derived from the `portfolio` array and the current route path param.

Assuming the route path is declared as something like `path="/portfolio/:path"`, use the `useParams` hook to get the currently matched `path` param and search the `portfolio` array.

Example:

```
const { path } = useParams();
const [ite, setItem] = useState();

const { portfolio } = useGlobalContext();

useEffect(() => {
  setItem(portfolio.find(item => item.path === path));
}, [path, portfolio]);

...
```

From here you can tweak your prev/next logic to update the route path and let `react-router-dom` and the `useEffect` hook rerender and load the correct portfolio item.

Comment: @itsMe Welcome, glad it seems sufficient for you. Cheers and good luck!